# How to document choices in api platform?

Tags: api-platform.com

In API-platform, how do I document the choices for a specific property? I have for example a property deliveryTimeWindow:

```
/**
 * @var string The delivery timewindow of this order.
 *
 * @ORM\Column
 * @Assert\Choice(callback="getTimeWindows")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $deliveryTimeWindow;
```

But the only thing I see in the front-end is an example "string".

How do I inform to my end-users that only a specific choice is allowed?

Comment: Can you send http header codes, depending the kind of data received? If so you can use the http code `400 malformed` or another one: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1

Comment: @var should work and does for me. Can you post a screenshot or something where we can see what exactly your front-end displays?